# PHP Loop through JSON

Tags: php, json

Sorry about another one of these.

The json comes back in this format:

```
{
   "data":{
      "internalName":"hotshotgg",
      "name":"HotshotGG",
      "acctId":434582,
      "profileIconId":531,
      "revisionDate":"\/Date(1357002079809)\/",
      "summonerLevel":30,
      "summonerId":407750
   },
   "success":true
}
```

Also seen here: http://elophant.com/developers/docs/summoner

The data comes back correctly:

```
Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [internalName] => nemonorm 
        [name] => nemonorm 
        [acctId] => 28685607 
        [profileIconId] => 544 
        [revisionDate] => /Date(1361354064000)/ 
        [summonerLevel] => 30 
        [summonerId] => 24286314 
    ) 
    [success] => 1 
)
```

I can't seem to loop through and print out the information I want:

```
$decode= json_decode($url, true);

foreach($decode['data'] as $key => $value) {
    echo  $value['name'] . " <br />";
}
```

Pretty sure it's something obvious... But I can't see it.

Comment: Any errors?   Something?

Comment: The string "can't seem to loop through" is not a built-in error message in PHP.

Comment: @JackManey Maybe it's coming from some external extension?

Comment: `E_PEBKAC can't seem to loop through`

Comment: I wonder if there's a layer of hell where the tormented have to deal with tickets having descriptions like "it won't work" or "I can't loop through here".

Comment: Are you sure the data is in `$url`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the contents of the URL first for example with curl:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$decode = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then on top of that it looks like youre anticipating the wrong data structure. If you want to echo the `data.name` then you jsut access that. If you wanted to echo all the data then you need to loop.

```
// echo the name only:
echo $decode['data']['name'];

// echo all data
foreach($decode['data'] as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array isn't deep enough. What you have is:

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [internalName] => nemonorm
        ...
    ) [success] => 1
)
```

When you loop through $decoded['data'] the values you're getting are individual variables, not arrays. By that I mean $value is a string, not an array, so $value['name'] is meaningless. What you need is this:

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [internalName] => nemonorm
            ...
        )
    ) [success] => 1
)
```

Then you'll be looping through an array of results, rather than the values of a single result.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell with the information we have, but is $url the contents of the URL, or just the actual URL?  You need to obtain the contents first, before calling json_decode on them.

Something like:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
```

Try looking at cURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php for another method of obtaining the contents of the URL.

Comment: I added what data is pulled back, it uses a unique key so didn't really want to post it.  It's there, just cant loop through it..